# UserDefaults randomly not working (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

Saving and retrieving userDefaults seems to only work randomly (all of a sudden - I am SO sure it was working correctly a few days ago!).

I can't see anything wrong with my implementation:

```
// UtilityFunctions.swift

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

func saveCurrentGraph(graphName: String) {
    debugPrint("UtilityFunctions--saveCurrentGraph: \(graphName)")
    defaults.set(graphName, forKey: "CurrentGraph")
}

func getSavedGraph() -> String {
    if let savedGraph = defaults.string(forKey: "CurrentGraph") {
        debugPrint("UtilityFunctions--getSavedGraph: \(savedGraph)")
        return savedGraph
    }
    return ""
}
```

I added some debug statements in various places:

in AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    debugPrint("----------Launch start (AppDelegate)---------")
    for (key, value) in defaults.dictionaryRepresentation() {
        if key == "CurrentGraph" {
            debugPrint("value retrieved at launch: \(key) = \(value)")
        }
    }
    debugPrint("----------Launch end (AppDelegate)-----------")   
}
```

in ViewController.swift

```
var currentGraph = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    currentGraph = getSavedGraph()
    debugPrint("value retrieved in viewDidLoad: \(currentGraph)")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    debugPrint("value retrieved in viewWillAppear: \(currentGraph)")
    createGraphView()
}


func createGraph() {

    debugPrint("=========== createGraph start")
    // save the current graph
    debugPrint("currentGraph = \(currentGraph)")
    saveCurrentGraph(graphName: currentGraph)

    for (key, value) in defaults.dictionaryRepresentation() {
        if key == "CurrentGraph" {
            debugPrint("stored value: \(key) = \(value)")
        }
    }
    debugPrint("=========== createGraph end")

}
```

Here are some sample results:

```
"----------Launch start (AppDelegate)---------"
"value retrieved at launch: CurrentGraph = John"
"----------Launch end (AppDelegate)-----------"

"UtilityFunctions--getSavedGraph: Betsy"
"value retrieved in viewDidLoad: Betsy"
"UtilityFunctions--getSavedGraph: Betsy"
"value retrieved in viewWillAppear: Betsy"

"=========== createGraph start"
"currentGraph = Betsy"
"UtilityFunctions--saveCurrentGraph: Betsy"
"stored value: CurrentGraph = John"
"=========== createGraph end"
```

I can see that the correct value was stored when reading the userDefaults dictionary in the AppDelegate.

But then, when I call the `getSavedGraph` method, it returns an old value.

And when I save a new value in the `createGraph` method, it appears to be fine, but reading back the userDefaults dictionary it again, shows the very first value as read at launch.

Am I doing something wrong???

Comment: try with **defaults.synchronize()** when you are saving your value.

Comment: I have read that Apple does not want us to use synchronize anymore.  I tried it but it did not work.

Comment: Let me run your code on my machine.

Comment: I can't see where you are calling **createGraph()** Method

Comment: Sorry, it is in `viewWillAppear`. (I just added it in the OP.)

Comment: The defaults database is updated asynchronously. in practice it's pointless to save a value and read it back immediately.

Comment: @vadian - Shouldn't defaults.synchronize() overcome that?  In use, I actually spent a bit of time looking at the graph - 30 seconds plus should be more than enough, shouldn't it?

Comment: Consider that UserDefaults is the wrong place to save values temporarily. For example don't use it to share data between view controllers. And as a long term storage the time of responsiveness actually doesn't matter in practice.

Comment: It's really only there so that when I launch the app the next time, I pick up where I left off.

Comment: Yes, it is, and for the very rare cases – actually there are none –  that you need to update the database at once there is `synchronize`.